# CRC32 calculation

Tags: python, crc, crc32

I am trying to write some python code to test my hardware CRC module in the micro. The python code will calculate the crc value for a random data block and it will compare with the crc value returned from the micro for the same random data block.

Answer (score 2):

Q1:  This should get you started making random blocks:

```
def randblock(nbytes):
    x = random.randrange(256 ** nbytes)
    return binascii.unhexlify('%0*x' % (nbytes*2, x))
```

Q2:  The [zlib.crc32](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32) function can be seeded with any value you want -- just pass that value as the second argument.  The default seed is zero.

Q3:  Yes, passing the data to the crc32() will generate a reasonable CRC value.